# Rest of script not running after calling a batch file to run?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, notepad

I have the following script `batch` script:

```
call standalone.bat

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\Program Files\jboss-eap-6.2\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\log\server.log"
```

The first command runs as expected but the script never seems to call notepad to open the server.log file.

What is the issue here?

Edit: ending of `standalone.bat` is:

```
if ERRORLEVEL 10 goto RESTART

:END
if "x%NOPAUSE%" == "x" pause

:END_NO_PAUSE
```

Comment: The script you show is fine. I guess, there is a hard `exit` in `standalone.bat`, which causes the window to close instead of returning to the calling script. If so, replace it with a `goto :eof`. If not, show us `standalone.bat` (also a severe syntax error could cause this issue)

Comment: If what you've posted is really your script, as opposed to just part of it, I'd suggest you modify it to `@Call standalone.bat`, and `@Start "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%ProgramFiles%\jboss-eap-6.2\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\log\server.log"`.

Comment: I have now edited question with the ending of standalone.bat

Comment: @java12399900 - the `EXIT` command could appear anywhere within the standalone.bat script. Also, a fatal syntax error would prevent return, though you should then see an error message unless stderr has been redirected.

Comment: Are you sure standalone is actually finishing? Are you sure the standalone.bat isn't executing the PAUSE at the end? (obviously it won't end until you press a key) You haven't described what "first command runs as expected" means. What happens if you run standalone.bat directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stephan likely diagnosed the problem in his [question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058859/rest-of-script-not-running-after-calling-a-batch-file-to-run#comment115018651_65058859) - standalone.bat probably terminates with an `exit` command. If that is correct, then you can work around the problem without modifying standalone.bat by changing
`call standalone.bat`
to
`cmd /c standalone.bat`.

Comment: I have now edited question with the ending of standalone.bat